# How do you convert a float to an integer so that it can be used in randint

Tags: python

I'm making a game and I have a feature that when the player levels up, their health increases. There is also a function that when the player rests, it heals the player for a random amount between 1 and a quarter of their max health. The max health at level 2 is 30 so when quartered, goes to 7.5 and this doesn't work in a randint(1, p_maxhealth) and gives me this error;

> ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange().

I've tried converting the float to an int after quartering it but doing; int(round(p_maxhealth)) but it doesn't update the value to the int data type. Does anyone know how to work around this without manually setting the health to a new value as I would prefer not to :)

here is my code:

```
p_hp = 25
p_maxhp = 30

rested_maxhp = p_maxhp / 4
int(round(rested_maxhp))  
print(rested_maxhp)
rested_hp = randint(1,rested_maxhp) 
print(rested_hp)
p_hp = min(p_hp + rested_hp, p_maxhp)   
print(p_hp)
```

Comment: Use floor division `p_maxhp // 4`. It will round down the value to 7 automatically.

Comment: Also you need to save to value as well after the rounding and casting `rested_maxhp = int(round(rested_maxhp)) `. int is immutable.

Comment: Maybe switch to percentage? So if you can restore between 25 and 100 percent, you just do random in this range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the `int()` function doesn't change the variable itself, so this would work:

```
from random import randint
p_hp = 25
p_maxhp = 30

rested_maxhp = p_maxhp / 4

rested_maxhp = int(round(rested_maxhp)) //This changed

print(rested_maxhp)

rested_hp = randint(1, rested_maxhp)

print(rested_hp)

p_hp = min(p_hp + rested_hp, p_maxhp)

print(p_hp)
```